# Parsing XML using the xpath.js NPM Module

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xpath

My XML looks like this:

```
<jobs>
  <job>
    <title>Engineer - System Planning</title>
    <url>http://my.jobs/0629cdc680d04cf3bcd711a1c0b69836321</url>
    <company>Iberdrola USA</company>
    <location>Augusta, ME</location>
    <dateacquired>2013-3-22 6:24 PM</dateacquired>
    <jvid>0629cdc680d04cf3bcd711a1c0b69836321</jvid>
  </job>
  <job>
    <title>Engineer - Hydro</title>
    <url>http://my.jobs/61cccbfba50c4f93a5169aafc13c82b2321</url>
    <company>Iberdrola USA</company>
    <location>Rochester, NY</location>
    <dateacquired>2013-7-5 8:33 PM</dateacquired>
    <jvid>61cccbfba50c4f93a5169aafc13c82b2321</jvid>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

And I am wanting to use the XPath.js NPM Module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath.js). but I am just not sure how to loop through each `job` in the XML document using that module

Comment: The readme for xpathjs contains plenty of good examples for that. Are you asking how to use npm packages in meteor or are you asking ho to construct an xpath query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first example in the [xpath.js documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath.js), with an XPath expression like `//job` you'll get a node-set:

```
var nodes = select(doc, "//job");
```

which you can loop using regular JavaScript, since it's an array. You can then pass each node as a parameter in another XPath expression and obtain the data inside the other nodes:

```
for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var title   = select(nodes[i], "title/text()")[0].data;
    var url     = select(nodes[i], "url/text()")[0].data;
    var company = select(nodes[i], "company/text()")[0].data;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had looked at the documentation for so long that I just was having a hard time discerning it all